# How do you denote and define the slope of the complex tangent plane to a function from $\Bbb C$ to $\Bbb R$?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

Consider the function

\begin{align}
f: \Bbb C &\to \Bbb R\\
f(x) &\mapsto \frac{\lvert x\rvert^2}2
\end{align}

What is the complex slope of the tangent plane at $(x, f(x)$.  If this isn't $f'(x)$, does it have a name?

Also, what is $f'(x)$?  What is its range and how is it defined in terms of limits?  WolframAlpha seems to be [defining this somehow](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative%20of%20abs%28x%5E2%29%2F2%20at%20x%3D1%2B1i).

Comment: You can't unless the derivative is zero.

Comment: @copper.hat I'll edit the question to clarify what I actually mean then.

Comment: The only linear map $L:\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{R}$ is $L=0$.

Comment: @copper.hat I don't know why we're talking about linearity when I gave a quadratic example?

Comment: The derivative of $f:A \to B$ is a linear map $A \to B$, so if none exists (at least no non trivial one) then $f$ cannot be differentiable. You would need to elaborate what you mean by a tangent space to the graph of $f$ means.

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks, okay, could you see my edits?   I mean the complex slope of the tangent plane to the above paraboloid.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what that means. Even if you embed the graph into $\mathbb{C}^2$ I don't think there is a unique plane supporting the graph.

Comment: @copper.hat The graph is a paraboloid, right?  I don't see why it doesn't have a unique plane tangent to it at every point $(x, f(x)$?  If I had written $x=a+bi$, then couldn't I define the tangent plane $df(x)/da + i df(x)/db$?

Comment: You can certainly do it as a map $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$. I may be nitpicking on something that is not relevant to your interest, but keep in mind that $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ have differences that may matter in some circumstances. Differentiability being a big example (which is how the question was posed initially).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116673/discussion-between-neil-g-and-copper-hat).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a continuous function $f:\Bbb{R}^n \to \Bbb{R}^k$ with continuous partial derivatives, we look at the **directional derivative** $$D_v f(a) = \lim_{h\to 0,h\in \Bbb{R}}\frac{f(a+tv)-f(a)}{t}, \qquad a,v\in \Bbb{R}^n$$
For each fixed $a$ then $v\to D_v f(a)$ is a $\Bbb{R}$-linear map, which is just $$D_v f(a)=\sum_{j=1}^n v_j \partial_{x_j} f(a)$$
It works the same way for your function under the identification $\Bbb{C}\cong \Bbb{R}^2$, $n=2,k=1$.

Your 'tangent plane' is $(a,f(a))+\Bbb{R}(1,D_1(a))+\Bbb{R}(i,D_i(a))$.

As you see no complex slope appears.

When $f:\Bbb{C\to C}$, again with the identification $\Bbb{C}\cong \Bbb{R}^2$, if $v\to D_vf(a)$ is $\Bbb{C}$-linear then $f$ is said complex differentiable at $a$, and holomorphic when it is so at every $a$ on an open.

Comment: Thank you for your well-written answer.  I don't understand why in the case that $f: \Bbb C \to \Bbb R$, we don't define $f'(a)$ to mean $D_1 f(a) - i D_i f(a)$ since the Taylor approximation around $f(a)$ based on directional derivatives would be $f(a + v) = f(a) + Re( f'(a) v) + O(||v||^2)$?

Comment: You can represent $v\to D_v f(a)$ as you want